# How to use quaternions in ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, quaternion, transformation

I have to use some sort of transformations to generate velocity of a model using global coordinates. This code is for making the model go to specific locations (goals). the problem i am facing is that the error_x and other values are calculated using global frame but the linear and angular velocity is always given in body frame of the model. i figured that maybe quaternions can help me achieve this task. i need help regarding this.

```
            error_x = x_goal - ebot_controller.loc_x
            error_y = y_goal - ebot_controller.loc_y
            error_theta = theta_goal- ebot_controller.loc_theta
            print("X(Error): ", error_x, " Y(Error):", error_y)
            # Calculation of control outputs using a P controller
            ebot_controller.vel.linear.x = ebot_controller.kp_x * error_x
            ebot_controller.vel.linear.y = ebot_controller.kp_y * error_y
            ebot_controller.vel.angular.z = ebot_controller.kp_theta * error_theta

            ebot_controller.cmd_vel_pub_.publish(ebot_controller.vel)
            # code below is for not letting the model crawl to the goal very slowly
            if error_x < 0.1 and y_goal < 0.1:
             ebot_controller.index += 1
             if ebot_controller.flag == 1:
                ebot_controller.index = 0
                ebot_controller.send_request(ebot_controller.index)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In robotics, a quaternion (i.e. 4 coordinates) is typically used as a representation of a 3D orientation. There are other possible representations for the same 3D orientation, e.g. a minimal set of 3 coordinates (Euler angles, Roll Pitch Yaw, etc.), a 3x3 rotation matrix (i.e. 9 coordinates), etc.

For your case, your robot only has a 1D orientation, and you already have a representation for that orientation: it is given by the angle `ebot_controller.loc_theta`. You *could* express this orientation in terms of a quaternion, but there is no real need for that.

The relation between the global and local coordinate system is given by:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_{x\_global}\\ v_{y\_global}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&-sin(\theta)\\
sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}v_{x\_ local}\\ v_{y\_local}\end{bmatrix}
$$
and inverse:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_{x\_local}\\ v_{y\_local}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&sin(\theta)\\
-sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}v_{x\_global}\\ v_{y\_global}\end{bmatrix}
$$

The rotational component is unchanged, i.e.:
$$
\omega_{global} = \omega_{local}
$$